# Form element doesn't send all data to mongoDB by using axios. (React,Axios,Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to send data from the HTML form element in React to MongoDB by using Express.js. But it sends only the last input value from the Form element. Actually, It shows the last input value as data in the console. When I look at MongoDB I can see just id and createdAt, updatedAt. There is no rest of the data.

This is my Form.jsx file;

````
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Form = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState({
       fName:"",
       lName:"",
       age:"",
    });



    const handleOnChange = (event) =>{
        const value = event.target.value;
        setState({
            ...setState,
            [event.target.name]: value
        })

        console.log(state);
    }
    const postHandleClick = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();  
        
        axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/", state)
        .then(res =>{
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err);
        });

    }
    return(
        <div className= "form-container">

            <form  action="http://localhost:5000/form" method="get">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Show Clients</button>
            </form>


            <form className="myForm" onSubmit={postHandleClick}>
                <div className="form-group">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" name="fName" onChange={handleOnChange} value={state.fName} placeholder="Name"/>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label>Last Name</label>
                  <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lName" onChange={handleOnChange} value={state.lName} placeholder="Lastname "/>
                </div>

.
.  // there are many input and label elements
.

 <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>

            
        </div>
    );
}


export default Form;


```

This is my index.js (in server folder)

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import router from "./routes/clients.js";
import cors from "cors";

//all these code for defining __dirname because of node 14 version
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use(cors());


app.use(express.static("../../client/public"));



app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "../../client/public/index.html")
});

app.use(router);


const CONNECTION_URL = "mongodb+srv://admin-muhammet:37463746NBA@cluster0.zlysq.mongodb.net/dietManageDB";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true})
    .then(() => app.listen(5000, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

This is client.js (controller from server)

```
import Client from "../models/client.js";

export const createClientInfo =  (req, res) => {
    
    const newClientInfo = new Client(    
    {
        fName: req.body.fName,
        lName: req.body.lName,
        email: req.body.email,
        tel: req.body.telNumber,
        gender: req.body.gender,
        pregnancy: req.body.pregnancy,
        dob : {
            year: req.body.year, 
            month: req.body.month, 
            day: req.body.day,
        },
        currentWeight: req.body.weight,
        currentHeight: req.body.height,
        job: req.body.job,
        city: req.body.city,
        sporDuringDiet: req.body.sporDuringDiet,
        alcohol: req.body.alcohol,
        cigarette: req.body.cigarette,
        frequencySport:req.body.frequencySport,
        glassWater: req.body.glassWater,
        useSugar: req.body.useSugar,
        chronicIllness: req.body.chronicIllness,
        usingMedicine: req.body.usingMedicine,
        menopause: req.body.menopause,
        allergy: req.body.allergy,
        snack: {
            brkfstToNoon: {
                time: req.body.brkfstToNoonTime,
                food: req.body.brkfstToNoonFood,
            },
            noonToNight: {
                time: req.body.noonToNightTime,
                food: req.body.noonToNightFood
            },
            nightToSleep: {
                time: req.body.nightToSleepTime,
                food: req.body.nightToSleepFood,
            }
        },

    
    });

    newClientInfo.save();
    res.redirect("/form");
};


export const indexClientInfo = async(req, res) => {
    
    try {
        const client = await Client.find({});
        res.status(200).json(client);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({message: error.message});
    }
    
}


export default {
    createClientInfo,
    indexClientInfo
};
```

this is the data from mongodb that form element sent

```
{
"_id": "6063c13015191b0b78643c5a",
"createdAt": "2021-03-31T00:24:16.152Z",
"updatedat": "2021-03-31T00:24:16.152Z",
"__v": 0
}
```

this is what the console shows; (First three objects I added, rest of the objects are created by form data. I want to add my form element send data as first 3 objects)

```
{data: Array(7), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://localhost:5000/", method: "post", data: "{"allergy":"no allergy"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: Array(7)
0: {dob: {…}, snack: {…}, _id: "60607311264562474c006ff8", name: {…}, email: "muhammed@gmail.com", …}
1: {dob: {…}, snack: {…}, _id: "60622a2efc81265d2828f52e", name: {…}, email: "muhammed@gmail.com", …}
2: {dob: {…}, snack: {…}, _id: "60628b38a6f18b6e4088ae18", name: {…}, email: "muhammed@gmail.com", …}
3: {_id: "60631a99d4f4e15818c68c7e", createdAt: "2021-03-30T12:33:29.928Z", updatedat: "2021-03-30T12:33:29.928Z", __v: 0}
4: {_id: "60631abad4f4e15818c68c7f", createdAt: "2021-03-30T12:34:02.959Z", updatedat: "2021-03-30T12:34:02.959Z", __v: 0}
5: {_id: "6063c13015191b0b78643c5a", createdAt: "2021-03-31T00:24:16.152Z", updatedat: "2021-03-31T00:24:16.152Z", __v: 0}
6: {_id: "6063c1e615191b0b78643c5b", createdAt: "2021-03-31T00:27:18.180Z", updatedat: "2021-03-31T00:27:18.180Z", __v: 0}
length: 7
__proto__: Array(0)
headers: {content-length: "2794", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
__proto__: Object
```

Thanks for help.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the `setState` call inside the `handleOnChange` function where you're spreading the `setState` function instead of `state`.

```js
setState({
  ...setState, // {...setState} returns {}
  [event.target.name]: value,
})
```

should be

```js
setState({
  ...state,
  [event.target.name]: value,
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I tried it and it helps me to show data on the console correctly. But I didn't send data to the database. Finally, I solved the problem. The problem was many things. This video helped me for solving my problem. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUbNn0voiBI

Also, here is the another solutions:
```
    const handleOnChange = (event) =>{
        const {name, value} = event.target;
        setState(prevInput=> {
            return{
                ...prevInput,
                [name]: value
            }
        })

        console.log(state);
    }
```